# Takin' muh niece on a tour

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story, geography

> Muh niece Nancy was bored o' starin' at four walls so I took 'er on a tour. We went on muh sailboat, had chicken breast fo' dinner, and bought those li'l cans o' fruit juice that she likes. Went to see the lions in the zoo an' ev'rythin'. Dun' want 'er to lose 'er mind or nothin'.

Where are we?

Hint:

> There are ten clues. Extra points for finding them all :)

Comment: A well-known zoo is the San Diego Zoo and it is pretty close to the shore for sailboats I think

Comment: @Duck you may be onto something. They also have chicken and fruit juice in San Diego, I believe! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are in ...

> ... **France**.

The phonetically awkward story ...

> ... has the names of ten French cities hidden in it:
>
>  Muh **Nice** **Nancy** was **Bordeaux** starin' at four walls so I took 'er on a **Tours**. We went on **Marseilles** boat, had chicken **Brest** fo' dinner, and bought those **Lille** **Cannes** o' fruit juice that she likes. Went to see the **Lyons** in the zoo an' ev'rythin'. Dun' want 'er **Toulouse** 'er mind or nothin'.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you may be at

> a Wings concert

because

> Muh niece Nancy $\rightarrow$ Uncle Albert
>  starin' at four walls $\rightarrow$ Band on the run lyrics
>  see the lions $\rightarrow$ sealions in Junior's Farm

if i'm right, i'm missing 70% though!